# Плагин браузера

Tags: windows, веб-программирование

Есть ли принцип или какая-либо литература по созданию общебраузерного плагина (не как firebug с разрозненной установкой для каждого, а вот как напр. Flash Player. Он же кидает какие-то библиотеки в рут)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На IE используется ActiveX, на остальных (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) - NPAPI. Для создания чего-то кросс-браузерного, можно взять [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/).

Comment: Про NPAPI спасибо, помогло.